# Why am I getting a "type 'bool' is not iterable" if I am not trying to iterate?

Tags: python

Could someone with superior python skills please explain why am I getting a "bool is not iterable" error, when I am only doing some dict lookups and comparisons?

This is the last line of the stack trace:

```
---> 54     if 'identifiers' in document and 'doi' in document['identifiers'] and document['identifiers']['doi'] == row['doi']:
     55         print 'Found DOI'
     56         return True

TypeError: ("argument of type 'bool' is not iterable", u'occurred at index 2914')
```

Is best practice to use a `try/except` to attempt to read my dict and catch if the key does not exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When an object doesn't provide `contains()`, `in` attempts to iterate it (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

```
>>> print 1 in True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable
>>>
```

The problem seems to be that the key does exist, but has the wrong type, so the `in` check isn't helpful here. Generally, in python it's better to follow [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) and handle an exception instead of trying to pre-check everything.

Comment: ah, that explains it.

Comment: what is the pythonic way of doing this type of check? I basically want to do the last comparison, but was trying to avoid the error if either of the keys (identifiers, doi) were not present

Comment: perfect. Replaced code with:  try: 
        if document['identifiers']['doi'] == row['doi']: ... except: .... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

document['identifiers'] is a bool type, and the 'in' is trying to iterate over a bool variable which is giving you this error.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this is the cause of your error, but you can use the get method:

`dict.get(key, default=None)`

You can define an optional default value to return if the key is not present, and it won't trip an error.